# Explanation of items/buttons on User Profile Frame

Tags: hay-day

When visiting someones farm, a number of possible buttons and icons appear on their User Profile Frame.

I have circled and marked these for easier reference:
[image: User Profile Frame]

### 1. Exclamation Mark Icon

I assume that this is to indicate that there is something on the farm you can help him with? I might be wrong though, so what does this Icon represent?

### 2. Emblem/Badge Icon

What does this one represent?

### 3. Star with number

This is the players level?

### 4. Ribbon Icon/Button

This is to 'Follow' or 'Bookmark' someones farm?

### 5. Message/Mail Icon/Button

What is this one for?

### 6. Smiley Icon/Button

This is to 'Like' someones farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have leveled enough to start making use of all these things, and here is the answer(s):

### 1. Exclamation Mark Icon

Indicates that something requires another players help on this farm. This includes reviving trees/bushes and helping fill up a boat order.

### 2. Emblem/Badge Icon

This is the neighborhood (guild/group) the player belongs to.

### 3. Star with number

This is the players Level.

### 4. Ribbon Icon/Button

This is to follow the farm. It will subsequently show up under your friends list.

### 5. Message/Mail Icon/Button

This is used to invite the player to join your neighborhood (guild/group).

### 6. Smiley Icon/Button

This is used to 'Like' the players farm.